# To get user's profile information in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get my domain's user's profile information..I am using profile API for this..

Profile API gives only a few fields like (Family Name, Given Name,Email etc)..But i also want to get these fields also: 
occupation,department,Phone [Work], Phone [Mobile], Relation [Manager]...

i am not able to get these fields..So please give me suggestion to get these fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my all fields by Profile API.... Actually if any field is empty then Profile API doesn't give that field as an output.....
So using Profile API, we can get a user's full information....

```
Code :
    var username="user "
    var base = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'; 
    var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('contacts', base);
    fetchArgs.method='GET'
    var url=base+'profiles/domain/'+domainName+'/full/'+username+'?v=3&alt=json'

    var name=""
    var occupation=""
    var department=""
    var email=""
    var contactNumber_1=""
    var contactNumber_2=""
    var relation=""
    var account=""
    var office=""
    var personal_account=""
    var current_account=""
    var language=""
    var blog=""
    var image=""
    try{
      var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs)   
      var json=Utilities.jsonParse(urlFetch.getContentText())
      var profileInfo = json.entry
      try{
        name=profileInfo.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t
      }catch(err){}
      try{
        occupation=profileInfo.gContact$occupation.$t
      }catch(err){}
      try{
        department=profileInfo.gd$organization[0].gd$orgDepartment.$t
      }catch(err){}
      try{
        var emaillist=profileInfo.gd$email
        for(var i=0;i<emaillist.length;i++){
          if(emaillist[i].rel.split("#")[1]=='work')
            email=profileInfo.gd$email[i].address
        }
      }catch(err){}
      try{
        var phonelist=profileInfo.gd$phoneNumber
        for(var i=0;i<phonelist.length;i++){
          if(phonelist[i].rel.split("#")[1]=='work')
            contactNumber_1=phonelist[i].$t
          else if(phonelist[i].rel.split("#")[1]=='mobile')
            contactNumber_2=phonelist[i].$t
        }
      }catch(err){}
      try{   
        relation=profileInfo.gContact$relation[0].$t+" ["+profileInfo.gContact$relation[0].rel+"]"
      }catch(err){}  

    }catch(err){}

}


/*
  Oauth Authentication
*/

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

If any field is empty then that tag will not be found thats why all the fields are written in try - catch block...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in API for that in Apps Script directly, but if you are using a Google Apps for Business or Education, you can use the Google Apps  through [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch) and [oAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_oauthconfig). That should expose any profile information that is stored in Google Apps.

Comment: ya, exactly...we can get user's information using Profile API and oAuth